# Como adicionar mais produtos?

Tags: php

Estou criando uma sistema de "vendas" pessoal pra empresa do meu pai. Só que estou com um problema. Só consigo vender um produto por vez, sou novo no PHP então não seu muito o que fazer.

Quero fazer um "carrinho" e consiga adicionar 2 ou mais produtos. Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
session_start();
include("includes/conexa.php");
include("includes/topo.php");

$busca = $_POST['produto'];
    $_SESSION['produto'] = $busca;
$qnts = $_POST['quantidade'];
    $_SESSION['quantidade'] = $qnts;


    $produto1 = array($_SESSION['produto']);
    $qnts1 = array($_SESSION['quantidade']);
    var_dump($produto1);
    var_dump($qnts1);

    $produto2 = array($_SESSION['produto2']);
    $qnts2 = array($_SESSION['quantidade2']);
    var_dump($produto2);
    var_dump($qnts2);

    

Continuar Comprando
```

E se eu clicar em "continuar comprando", refazer uma compra ela substitui a compra anterior.

E se não for muito incomodo, gostaria que vocês indicassem algum livro ou site em que eu consiga aprender mais sobre PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Por questões de segurança, recomendo usar um *Framework* próprio para criação de lojas virtuais, porque oferecem maior segurança, criar lojas dessa forma, normalmente é para pessoas que já têm conhecimento na área, e estão familiarizadas com as medidas de segurança, e normas de programação, ou ainda para aqueles que querem simplesmente entender a dinâmica de uma loja virtual.

Para ilustração, usarei uma `array` multidimensional para a vez do banco de dados, e os respectivos artigos nele. Mas antes, vamos iniciar uma sessão, e criar uma variável imutável (no sentido de resistir a *refeshes*):

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['cesto'])){
    $_SESSION['cesto'] = array();
}
```

E então a `array` com os produtos que serão usados no exemplo:

```
// produtos
$produtos = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'nome' => 'Lapis',
        'preco' => 50
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'nome' => 'Marcador',
        'preco' => 20
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'nome' => 'Borracha',
        'preco' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'nome' => 'Mochila',
        'preco' => 200
    )
);
```

Depois, vais precisar de lista-los da forma que quiseres, mas terás de definir um método de captura `GET` ou `POST`, claro que para o `POST` terias de usar *ajax* para poder dinamizar o processo, no caso usarei `GET` para construir uma `querystring` contendo o `id` do produto e a *acção* desejada.

```
// listar produtos
foreach($produtos as $produto){
    print "<p>{$produto['nome']} ({$produto['preco']}) - <a href=\"?produto={$produto['id']}&a=adicionar\">adicionar</a></p>";
}
```

Já se tem os produtos, a listagem dos produtos, variável que as vai manter, agora só falta o cesto, vejamos:

```
// cesto
if(!empty($_SESSION['cesto'])){
    $total = 0;
    print "<strong>cesto (" . count($_SESSION['cesto']) . ")</strong><br>";
    foreach($_SESSION['cesto'] as $item => $detalhes){
        print $detalhes['nome'] . " x " . $detalhes['quantidade'] . "<br>";
        $total += $detalhes['quantidade'] * $detalhes['preco'];
    }
    print "<strong>total: </strong>" . number_format($total, 2);
} else {
    print "<strong>cesto vazio</strong>";
}
```

Agora, para fazer com que o cesto funcione, para que sejamos capazes de adicionar os artigos nele:

```
// adicionar itens ao carrinho
if(isset($_GET['produto']) && isset($_GET['a'])){
    if($_GET['a'] == 'adicionar'){
        if(!empty($_SESSION['cesto'])){
            foreach($_SESSION['cesto'] as $item => $produto){
                if($item == $_GET['produto']){
                    $_SESSION['cesto'][$item]['quantidade'] = $produto['quantidade'] + 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    foreach($produtos as $produto){
                        if($produto['id'] == $_GET['produto']){
                            $_SESSION['cesto'][$produto['id']] = ['nome'=>$produto['nome'], 'preco'=>$produto['preco'], 'quantidade'=>1];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach($produtos as $produto){
                if($produto['id'] == $_GET['produto']){
                    $_SESSION['cesto'][$produto['id']] = ['nome'=>$produto['nome'], 'preco'=>$produto['preco'], 'quantidade'=>1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT :**
Para retornares os produtos através do banco de dados, podes fazer desta forma por exemplo.

```
$produtos = array();
$stmt =  $link->query("SELECT * FROM produtos");
while($linha = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($produtos, $linha);
}
```

> Recomendo que leias este tutorial [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp), lá podes ver melhor como manipular dados em *loops*, e como efectuar conexões com o banco de dados.
>   Podes ainda ver o código completo aqui no [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/W5V8yz5t).

Comment: Tenho um problema....
Sabe, na hora de listar os produtos. Eu fiz o seguinte : <pre>if(!isset($_SESSION['cesto'])){
 $_SESSION['cesto'] = array();
}

// produtos
 $consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM produtos");  
  while($linha = $consulta ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
      $id = "{$linha['id']}";
      $nome = "{$linha['nome']}";
      $preco = "{$linha['preco']}";
$produtos = array(
       array(
  'id' => $id,
  'nome' => $nome,
  'preco' => $preco 
 ),

);
}</pre>
Só que mostra somente um produto.

Comment: `$produtos = array( array( 'id' => $id, 'nome' => $nome, 'preco' => $preco ), )` troca isso por `array_push($produtos, $linha)`, mas antes declara `$produtos = array()` fora do `while`.

Answer (score 5):

Tem várias redundâncias no teu código, você usa `array` adicionando os valores da sessão sem necessidade, mas vamos direto ao ponto, tem como simplificar.

o item da sessão pode receber arrays normalmente, trabalhar com arrays ficará mais fácil.

> E se não for muito incomodo, gostaria que vocês indicassem algum livro ou site em que eu consiga aprender mais sobre PHP.

Não vou indiciar livros ou coisas assim pois este não é o foco do site, mas lhe indico a documentação do PHP:

- O que é array: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
- Usando if, for, while, etc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php
- Funções para manipular arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Um exemplo de carrinho de compras com array simples seria assim:

```
session_start();

//Cria o carrinho se não existir
if (!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])) {
   $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
}

$carrinho = $_SESSION['carrinho'];

//Verifica se as variáveis vieram via POST, se for adiciona um novo item ao carrinho
//NOTA: Recomendo validar essas variáveis, verificando se existem no banco ao invés de trazer tudo via post
if (isset($_POST['produto'], $_POST['quantidade'])) {
     //Adiciona ao array, note que [] equivale ao array_push()
     $carrinho[] = array(
         'produto' => $_POST['produto'],
         'quantidade' => (int) $_POST['quantidade']
     );
}

//Salva na sessão
$_SESSION['carrinho'] = $carrinho;

//Exibe produtos
foreach ($carrinho as $item) {
     var_dump($item['produto'], $item['quantidade']);
}
```

E se quiser somar a quantidade total de produtos independente do produto pode fazer no foreach assim:

```
$qtdCarrinho = 0;

//Exibe produtos
foreach ($carrinho as $item) {
     var_dump($item['produto'], $item['quantidade']);
     $qtdCarrinho += $item['quantidade'];
}

var_dump($qtdCarrinho);
```

Comment: @Miguel tem razão (acho que se refere ao if e não foreach), corrigido =)

Comment: ha, sim sim era ao if claro. Bom carrinho

Comment: E se eu quiser cancelar os produtos inseridos ? Posso criar um botão que da um stop na session ?

Comment: @AndreJunior para remover todos basta colocar na página de remoção isto `$_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();`, ou quando concluir a compra, vai setar uma variavel vazia novamente

Answer (score 2):

Defina um array multidimensional:

```
$_SESSION['cart']['items'] = array(
    'id' => 5, // código do produto
    'title' => 'produto teste', // título/nome do produto
    'selling_price' => 10.00 // preço de venda
    'quantity' => 5 // quantiadde
);
```

Seguindo o código original da sua pergunta, poderia ser algo assim

```
$_SESSION['produto'][10] = array(
    'nome' => 'produto teste',
    'preço' => 10.00,
    'quantidade' => 5
);
```

<sub>O `[10]` é o id do produto.</sub>

Por fim, a estrutura e nomenclatura é questão de opinião. O importante é montar um array multidimensional para poder organizar melhor e não precisa ter um índice específico somente para quantidade: `$_SESSION['quantidade']` pois dessa forma, quando precisar de mais índices ficará tudo muito disperso.

O exemplo acima é o mínimo que se pode fazer. Não quer dizer que deve manter a exata estrutura indicada. Adapte conforme a necessidade do seu projeto.

**Algumas observações sobre o exemplo:**

1. Não suporta múltiplas lojas.

   Para prover suporte a múltiplas lojas, exemplo, um shopping virtual com lojas diferentes, deve adicionar mais um nível ao array:

> ```
> $_SESSION['cart'][20]['items'] = array(
>   'id' => 5, // código do produto
>   'title' => 'produto teste', // título/nome do produto
>   'selling_price' => 10.00 // preço de venda
>   'quantity' => 5 // quantiadde
> );
> ```

Entre `cart` e `items`, adicionei `[20]`. Isso indica qual o ID da loja. No caso é ID 20, para exemplo.

2. Troca de idiomas pela interface do usuário

   Quando o site possui opção para trocar o idioma, os itens do carrinho devem acompanhar. Se o usuário está navegando em inglês e adicionar produtos, a session guardará o título em inglês. Ao trocar para outro idioma, português por exemplo, toda a interface estará em português, porém, os nomes dos produtos no carrinho estarão em inglês. Nesse caso, deve exibir o nome do produto conforme o idioma escolhido pelo usuário. Isso envolve questão de opinião, ou seja, pode ser feito de diversas formas.

   Isso pode ser contornado de forma mais prática buscando o nome do produto no banco de dados do que mantê-lo armazenado em session. Por outro lado, guardar na session otimiza a performance. Pense num esquema inteligente que una ambos os recursos.
3. Mudança no valor de venda.

   O valor final deve ser o valor inicial. Exemplo, se o usuário adicionou o produto no carrinho pelo preço de 50 reais, esse valor não pode ser alterado no momento que ele estiver no checkout (processo de finalização de compra).
   Algo que acontece em muitos sistemas de loja virtual é a sessão do carrinho possuir apenas o ID do produto. Sempre que precisar listar os itens do carrinho, é feito uma leitura no banco de dados. Não há problema nisso. O problema é quando o valor do produto é modificado durante esse meio tempo.

   Isso é como você estar num supermercado, pega um produto na prateleira por 50 reais, chega no caixa e tem que pagar 60 reais porque o sistema da loja mudou o preço enquanto você caminhava pelo local. 

   Em muitos países, e se não me engano, no Brasil, isso é ilegal por violar o direito do consumidor (propaganda enganosa). Pois o cliente tem o direito de pagar pelo preço que ele pegou da prateleira. Exceto em casos muito extremos como um preço realmente errôneo, muito fora do comum. Aí vai do bom senso e honestidade do cliente também.