# Por que não se deve usar um parâmetro booleano?

Tags: funções, estilo-de-codificação, engenharia-de-software, parâmetros, booleano

Já vi em alguns lugares que não se deve usar algo assim:

```
int teste(object obj, bool especial) { ... }
```

Aí dentro da função alguma operação será feita ou não, dependendo do que receber em `especial`.

Por que é ruim usar esta forma? O que seria melhor fazer então? Ter duas funções parece um exagero. Em alguns casos pode ficar confuso fazer funções separadas, pode gerar repetição e talvez até quebrar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Comment: No .Net framework (mscorlib) apenas 1.89% das funcoes disponibilizadas (públicas) tem um boleano como último argumento. Nao quer dizer nada, mas pode ser indicativo de quao comum essa pratica é usada.

Comment: @BrunoCosta sim, eu acho que deve-se usar onde cabe mesmo. Mas se analisar coisas novas apenas eu acho que tende a usar bem menos. De fato há muito caso que é abusivo.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Cada caso é um caso.

Toda vez que eu vejo alguma recomendação do tipo "não faça desta forma", "isto é má prática", "evite isso", eu espero a explicação do motivo logo em seguida. Se não houver um motivo pelo qual a técnica deve ser evitada, eu faço com a recomendação o que eu faço com propagandas no Youtube: ignoro em cinco segundos.

Vou dar um exemplo no qual receber um parâmetro booleano é válido, prático e desejável. Muita gente aqui vai dizer que se você tem um parâmetro booleano, é porque você está fazendo algo do tipo:

```cs
public function comprarIngressoCinema(bool tresD) {
    if (tresD) {
        foo();
    } else {
        bar();
    }
}
```

Então o correto seria criar dois métodos, `comprarIngressoCinema` e `comprarIngressoCinema3D`, fim da história, seu código ficou mais limpo e o casal real viveu feliz para sempre.

Quando na verdade o que você tem normalmente é:

```cs
public function comprarIngressoCinema(bool tresD) {
    reservarLugares();
    if (tresD) {
        foo();
    } else {
        bar();
    }
    verificarPromocoes();
    pacote = tresD ? especial : normal;
    pagamento(pacote);
    if (tresD) {
        enviarOculosParaSala();
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, você tem duas formas de lidar com isso. Você pode utilizar a metodologia `Go Horse`, que prega que você deve se preocupar apenas com o "como" e não se preocupar com coisas como os "porquês":

```cs
public function comprarIngressoCinema() {
    reservarLugares();
    bar();
    verificarPromocoes();
    pacote = normal;
    pagamento(pacote);
}

public function comprarIngressoCinema3D() {
    reservarLugares();
    foo();
    verificarPromocoes();
    pacote = tresD;
    pagamento(pacote);
    enviarOculosParaSala();
}
```

Haverá quem diga que o código ficou melhor porque você tem métodos curtos e mais legíveis. O problema é que a quantidade de código repetido é grande, e tende a crescer com o tempo. Cada vez que você tiver que dar manutenção aí, serão dois métodos para tratar. E vai piorar se você precisar incluir mais opções de cinema como iMax, por exemplo.

A alternativa é fazer como o Martin Fowler (apenas um programador que tem mais de vinte livros publicados sobre padrões de design e arquitetura de software) sugere em seu artigo [FlagArgument](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html) (em inglês). Foi a partir desse artigo que criei o meu exemplo. Seu código ficaria assim:

```cs
public function comprarIngressoCinema() {
    comprarIngressoCinema(false /*tresD*/);
}

public function comprarIngressoCinema3D() {
    comprarIngressoCinema(true /*tresD*/)
}

private function comprarIngressoCinema(bool tresD) {
    reservarLugares();
    if (tresD) {
        foo();
    } else {
        bar();
    }
    verificarPromocoes();
    pacote = tresD ? especial : normal;
    pagamento(pacote);
    if (tresD) {
        enviarOculosParaSala();
    }
}
```

Nós alteramos o código apresentado como público (que pode fazer parte das interfaces de uma API) para dois métodos sem parâmetros, que de fato é mais legível. Mas nós mantemos um método que recebe um parâmetro booleano. Porque assim como um utensílio de cozinha, uma ferramenta ou qualquer outra técnica de programação, **isso tem sua utilidade**, e se o efeito de seu uso vai ser bom ou ruim **depende da habilidade de quem usa e não da técnica em si**.

Comment: Era essa que eu queira :), se ninguém respondesse isso, eu responderia quase idêntico.

Comment: Martin fowler sempre salvando :D

Answer (score 6):

> Porquê é ruim ?

Porque, como já alguns aqui mencionaram, anula o princípio de coesão, onde funções com apenas um propósito, passam a desempenhar duas ou mais tarefas do que as originalmente projectadas, deixando o código difícil de se reestruturar quando necessário, reduz a legibilidade *(nem sempre)*, ou até mesmo duplicação de código ou responsabilidade, porque querendo ou não o código terá antes de verificar o *estado* do argumento, e escolher um caminho, sempre. Exemplo disso, poderia ser o uso de um método portador desse parâmetro em várias partes do código, onde estaria a verificar e a autorizar a mesma funcionalidade vezes e vezes. Ainda assim não deixa de ser útil em alguns casos.

Pessoalmente já algumas vezes me deparei com esse problema, enquanto fazia rasunhos, e um em especial, onde fui atribuindo `flags` a um método consoante as minhas necessidades, mas no final era quase doloroso inicializar esse método, porque não conseguia me identificar com as `flags` que defini, e tive até que criar uma documentação *"para um único método"*, porque mesmo que seja uma única, deve-se sempre saber o que faz.

```java
int public getA(obj n, bool a, bool b, bool c)
```

> O que seria melhor fazer então ?

Usar métodos complementares, ou simplesmente coesos, fazer o uso de `enum`, ou de forma geral, encapsular.

```cs
int teste(object obj, bool especial) { ... }
```

Por

```cs
int teste(object obj) { ... }
() testeEspecial(object obj) { ... }
```

Claramente o método criado, terá de seguir a mesma lógica de funcionamento que que lhe era atribuída aquando um dos seus estados implicava algo ao método que implementava.

```cs
enum Mock {
  mckA,
  mckB;
};

int teste(object obj, Mock tt.mockA) { ... }
```

Usado desta maneira, pode ser demasiado explícito relativamente aos detalhes de implementação de partes intimamente relacionadas, para partes mais externas da aplicação, já para não falar que o código dentro do método, fará também o uso de estruturas de condição para saber o que fazer. Tirando isso, em comparação aos *bool* pode-se definir mais de 2 estados ou valores num único *enum* e continua a ser viável.

```cs
int teste(object obj, bool especial, bool existe, bool grande) { ... }
```

Em casos mais simples, a implementação de uma `flag` ou argumento `booleano` aparece dessa forma:

```cs
int teste(object obj, bool especial) { 
    if(especial){
      // mais codigo
    } else {
      // mais codigo
    }
 }
```

Quando, criar diferentes métodos `testeEspecial` e `testeNormal` seria bem mais simples e eficiente. Noutros casos onde o uso de `flags` implica a utilização de várias estruturas de condição, como nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192826/como-adicionar-mais-produtos) por exemplo, pode ocorrer duplicação de código.

> Ter duas funções parece um exagero. Em alguns casos pode ficar confuso fazer funções separadas, pode gerar repetição e talvez até quebrar o DRY.

Como já antes disse, e realmente é o que eu acho, nem sempre é, por isso é relativo a situação.

Se for usado um argumento do tipo `bool` para activar certa funcionalidade em um método que eventualmente passará a desempenhar 2 ou mais funções além das originalmente pretendidas *(sem grande importância)*, e ao mesmo tempo declarares essa mesma funcionalidade em outro método, estaria a se criar uma duplicação do código. A verdade é que vai sempre existir um parte do código que se repete, o objectivo é evitar que isso aconteça, sempre que possível.

Answer (score 5):

Não dá para generalizar e definir que qualquer parâmetro `boolean` é um problema. Se é um problema ou não, vai variar do objetivo, contexto ou mesmo tamanho do método/classe que está recebendo este parâmetro booleano. E para resolvê-lo, também irá depender se estamos falando de uma classe ou método recebendo este parâmetro.

## Casos mais simples: poucos parâmetros

Por exemplo, se eu estiver querendo popular um objeto `Saldo`:

```
new Saldo("1.12", false);
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o valor do crédito e o segundo é um booleano indicando se o saldo entrando está bloqueado ou não.

Para um caso assim, simples e direto, este booleano não vai lhe gerar dores de cabeça ou confundi-lo no uso da classe.

Agora vamos ao método. Usando seu exemplo, teríamos uma chamada deste método assim:

```
teste(objeto, false);
```

Assim como ocorre com a classe, são poucos parâmetros e geralmente não criará confusões. Claro que quando vemos simplesmente um parâmetro `false`, não temos qualquer indicação do que aquilo significa fora da classe e método. Nestes casos simples, uma simples extração de variável pode ajudar:

```
 new Saldo("1.12", isSaldoBloqueado);
 teste(objeto, isEspecial);
```

Algumas linguagens também contam com **named parameters**, o que ajuda muito no entendimento do código e substitui esta técnica de extração de variável. Outras IDEs, como o Intellij IDEA do Java, por padrão mostram o nome das variáveis booleanas internas do método na sua chamada (simulando um *named parameter*), facilitando muito o entendimento do código.

Em casos simples assim, acabo sendo mais prático ao invés de tentar quebrar em vários métodos ou classes o código apenas para tentar sumir com o boolean. **Não estou dizendo que deixar assim é uma boa prática**, mas não quero ser extremista a ponto de falar que isto não deve existir em hipótese alguma no código. Mas, sem dúvida, são códigos que merecem atenção.

Deixemos isto para os casos mais complexos, explicados a seguir.

## Casos mais complexos: muitos parâmetros

Quando temos muitos parâmetros, a situação muda de figura. Imagine a seguinte instanciação de classe e chamada de métodos:

```
new Saldo("1,23", true, false, false);
teste(objeto, true, dataLimite, true, false);
```

Embora possa extrair algumas variáveis e melhorar a situação, nem sempre o resultado é satisfatório. Por ter mais variáveis booleanas, as chances de se confundir são maiores e, principalmente no caso do método, temos um inicio de *bad smell*: provavelmente este método está fazendo coisas demais ou o código internamente está confuso.

### Como resolver nos objetos?

Nos objetos, normalmente é mais simples resolver. Você tem duas opções:

1. Quebrar em mais classes, distribuindo melhor as responsabilidades
2. Usar um pattern como Builder.

Ou seja, para um objeto inicialmente assim: `new Saldo("1,23", true, false, false);`, poderíamos refatorar para ter:

```
new Saldo("1,23", new Bloqueado(true, dataLimite), new Composto(false, false));
```

Podendo usar, também, a própria presença do objeto ou não para compor o conteúdo do próprio objeto e usando diferentes construtores para isto. No exemplo acima, poderíamos ter dois construtores para Saldo, um deles aceitando o `Bloqueado` e o outro não.

Outra alternativa:

```
Saldo.builder
    .valor("1,23")
    .bloqueado(true)
    .dataLimite(dataLimite)
    .saldoComposto(false)
    .saldoCompostoBloqueavel(true)
    .build();
```

Particularmente não gosto do `Builder` se existir a possibilidade de refatorar para separar em mais objetos as informações. Com o `Builder`, você pode facilmente esquecer de definir uma das informações acima e quebrar seu código sem perceber.

Agora, no caso de métodos, as coisas podem complicar um pouco.

### Como resolver em métodos?

Com os métodos, temos mais opções, mas nem todas parecem boas. Vamos começar com um exemplo.

```
public String enviar (String mensagem, boolean erro) {

   if (!erro) 
      service.enviarSucesso(mensagem);
   else 
      service.enviarErro(mensagem);
}
```

Este método [tem mais de uma responsabilidade](https://blog.codinghorror.com/curlys-law-do-one-thing/). A chamada do mesmo seria:

```
enviar("mensagem", true);
```

Só quer você não quer ter este `boolean`. Para resolver este caso, você pode passar a responsabilidade para quem chama o método decidir:

```
enviarErro("mensagem");
enviarSucesso("mensagem");
```

Desta maneira, os métodos farão apenas uma única coisa (única responsabilidade). Contudo, isto **pode** resultar apenas em transferência da condição (mudar o `if` de classe), dependendo do código.

Outra alternativa, mais OOP, poderia ser:

```
Mensagem mensagem = new Sucesso("mensagem");
Mensagem mensagem = new Erro("mensagem");
```

Inclusive, no caso de uso de classes orientadas à objetos, [técnicas como Decorator](https://www.yegor256.com/2016/04/19/object-must-not-be-configurable.html) podem eliminar vários parâmetros booleanos, como demonstrado anteriormente no exemplo do `Saldo`.

Comment: `Não dá para generalizar e definir que qualquer parâmetro boolean é um problema` Eu faço a pergunta provocativamente mesmo, mas é bom dizer isso mesmo ;). Ainda vou ler com calma antes de votar, mas não gosto muito da ideia "aqui deveria não ser um booleano, mas é simples vou usar um assim mesmo". Mas depois mostra o adequado.

Answer (score 3):

Porque o código fica pouco indutivo, por exemplo , se alguém for dar manutenção ao seu código hoje, como esta pessoa vai saber o motivo daquele parâmetro booleano estar ali ? se for verdadeiro ou falso oque irá mudar ? Seria melhor usar uma enumeração ou constantes estáticas, desde que tenha um nome indutivo.
Outra opção seria separar este método em 2 funções com nome que indique a diferença.
Lembre-se também de sempre inserir comentários no seu código por garantia, porém sempre deixando o código intuitivo de maneira que não precise do mesmo. E mantenha documentação atualizada do código.

```
//enumeração
public enum OptionsEnum{
    EXECUTE_ALL,
    EXECUTE_PARTIAL;
}
test(obj, OptionsEnum.EXECUTE_ALL); 
test(obj, OptionsEnum.EXECUTE_PARTIAL); 


//constantes estática
public class Options{
    public final static int EXECUTE_ALL = 0;
    public final static int EXECUTE_PARTIAL = 1;
}
test(obj, Options.EXECUTE_ALL);
test(obj, Options.EXECUTE_PARTIAL);

//funções separadas
public testAll(Object obj){... ; testPartial(obj);}
public testPartial(Object obj){ ...}
testAll(obj);
testPartial(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

A divisão desta função em funções menores produzirá mais coesão, ou seja, uma função que faz uma coisa só. Dentro dessa função acabará tendo um `if` para verificar a condição e fazer a próxima ação necessário, não seria mais fácil dividi-la para ficar mais clara e reutilizável?

Veja o codigo:

```
int teste(object obj, bool especial) { 
   if(especial) {
      ...
   } else {
      ...
   }
}
```

Em termos de escrita será quase a mesma coisa, porém as funções estão separadas, facilitando caso você queira no futuro executar a função teste2() para outras operações.

```
int teste(object obj) { 
   if(condicao) {
      teste2();
   }
}

void teste2() {
   ...
}
```

Ou talvez:

```
int teste(object obj) { 
   if(teste2()) {
      ...
   }
}

boolean teste2() {
   ...
}
```

Portanto utilizar uma variável booleana pode não ser a melhor prática, mesmo escrevendo uma função a menos, pois nem sempre ficará mais clara e contextualizada com a operação principal da função.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizar parâmetro booleano evidencia que a função faz mais de uma coisa.

```
public static String render(PageData pageData, boolean isSuite) throws Exception {
   return new SetupTeardownIncluder(pageData).render(isSuite);
}
```

Uma chamada de método com somente um parâmetro do tipo booleano é bastante confusa:

```
render(true);
```

O ideal é separar em funções menores tornando o código mais legível:

```
renderForSuite();
renderForSingleTest()
```

Referência: [*Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)