# Argumentos booleanos, em geral, não são bons?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, independente-de-linguagem, booleano, argumento

Estava lendo um pouco do [Clean Code](https://pt.slideshare.net/rodrigokono/boas-prticas-tcnica-para-um-cdigo-limpo-clean-code). O livro fala sobre *"boas práticas de programação"*, e na internet, em um dos *slides* é dito que:

> Argumentos booleanos, em geral, não são bons.

Não entendi o motivo dessa frase. Apesar de não estar falando de uma linguagem específica, queria entender melhor o motivo.

- Essa frase é correta?
- Se sim, qual o problema com booleanos? Por que booleanos não são bons argumentos?
- Quais os tipos de argumento que seriam bons?

Comment: [Por que não se deve usar um parâmetro booleano?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193530/91)

Comment: Acho que é dup. né? E logo minha, nem lembrava dela. Acho que vou usar a resposta do Renan e talvez de outros pra melhorar a minha aqui.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Argumentos booleanos, em geral, não são bons. Essa frase é correta?

**Em geral** não são bons.

> Se sim, qual o problema com booleanos? Porque booleanos não são bons argumentos?

Ele dá pouco significado, torna o código menos legível. Então ele não causa problema técnico, é só uma questão de estilo.

Não me lembro se o livro explica isso ou não. Eu sei que esse livro não explica muita coisa. O que não é explicado não pode ser levado muito em conta.

Pode causar alguma dificuldade junto com outros mecanismos. Imagine que o parâmetro tem uma valor padrão `false` e você esquece disso, pode pegar um valor que não era o desejado, mas o problema aí não é o booleano em si, poderia ocorrer o mesmo com outros tipos.

Há o mito de que usando isso a função tem mais de uma responsabilidade. Isso é besteira porque não sabemos de antemão se tem ou não. Saber isso não garante nada. Alguns casos onde o booleano é usado pode ocorrer isso.

Esse é um daqueles argumentos errados que passam ser disseminados porque as pessoas não entendem o que está ocorrendo, só repetem o que leram/ouviram.

Claro que tem casos assim. Em geral é até melhor fazer assim quando o algoritmo precisa variar de acordo com uma informação que é apenas um detalhe do algoritmo.

Se criar dois métodos para evitar o argumento booleano a manutenção fica pior e fere o [princípio que uma alteração deve ser feita em apenas um lugar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) já que passa exigir sempre alteração em dois métodos e você pode esquecer de fazer no outro. É mais difícil esquecer de fazer no mesmo algoritmo e provavelmente o teste vai pegar o problema se estiver no mesmo.

O que pode ocorrer em certos casos é que isso diminui a [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101), mas depende, por isso não gosto de receitas de bolo, de boas práticas. Se a coesão está afetada, se a função realmente faz mais do que uma coisa, o problema não é o argumento ser booleano, o problema ocorre mesmo sem usar um booleano. Então olhar para o booleano é olhar para o problema errado.

Há quem diga que isso expõe um detalhe de implementação. Pode ocorrer em algum caso, mas não em todos, e a solução diferente disso, não importa qual, provavelmente terá o mesmo problema. [O Martin Fowler tem uma solução](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html).

Imagine um:

```
Compare(true);
```

O que esse argumento quer dizer?

> Quais os tipos de argumento que seriam bons?

Em geral preferimos uma enumeração com dois estados que indicam a mesma coisa que o verdadeiro e o falso, mas agora com nomes específicos que dizem alguma coisa. Então agora imagine:

```
Compare(Case.Sensitive);
```

Agora você sabe o que é o argumento? Dá muito mais contexto, certo?

Fica inclusive mais fácil de dar um *find* no código, né? Tem o que buscar. Procurar por um `true` não vai achar o que deseja.

Existe uma outra vantagem para um caso emergencial. Claro, esse tipo de solução não deveria ser necessária, mas nem sempre estamos em condições ideais. Pense que em algum momento você passar ter um terceiro estado para este algoritmo, o que fazer se você usou um booleano? Não tem muita solução a não ser criar outro argumento, se der sorte em uma linguagem que tem argumentos opcionais, caso contrário precisa de outra função. É bem feio. Se usar uma enumeração é só adicionar um novo membro nela, ainda que isso em geral [não seja o mais recomendável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101), não é tão crítico.

Outra solução é criar funções separadas para as duas tarefas e aí no nome dela terá um contexto do que está fazendo. Pode ser uma solução em certas situações. Assim:

```
CompareCaseSensitive();
```

Se a linguagem permitir o argumento nomeado, o booleano pode não ser tão ruim assim, desde que o consumidor da função nomeie o argumento sempre e seja garantido que um booleano sempre será adequado, algo assim:

```
Compare(CaseSensitive : true);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/BoolArgument.ptg).

Tem linguagem que chega obrigar o argumento ser nomeado em certos casos (Swift).

Veja mais em [Por que não se deve usar um parâmetro booleano?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193530/101).

Answer (score 0):

Achei esse artigo bastante interessante que poderá sanar sua dúvida. Segue um trecho do artigo.

"Essa é uma das piores práticas. Booleanos significa que sua função vai estar desempenhando um papel totalmente diferente dependendo do estado de apenas uma variavel. Isso fará com que nossa função tenha mais de uma responsabilidade, o que significa que qualquer alteração no código da função nós teremos que levar em consideração os outros papéis que a função está desempenhando."

Fonte: http://blog.triadworks.com.br/clean-code-boas-praticas-para-argumentos-de-funcao