# Qual é o equivalente do equalsIgnoreCase() no Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin

Qual é o equivalente do método `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` do Java no Kotlin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Para realizar esta comparação no Kotlin, passe o parâmetro "ignoreCase"      na função equals. 
Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
val texto1 = "testando";
val texto2 = "TESTANDO";
var resultado = texto1.equals(texto2, ignoreCase = true);
println(resultado);
```

Answer (score 8):

Os métodos que fazem sentido ter esta opção, e não só o `equals()` o fazem através de um parâmetro indicando a ignorância de caixa (*ignore case*). Veja a [documentação do `equals()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html). Veja também a [documentação da `String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html) de Kotlin. Observe que boa parte dos métodos tem este parâmetro.

Nesse ponto eu não sei se gostei da decisão do Kotlin já que [parâmetros booleanos costumam ser aceitos mais ou menos universalmente como má engenharia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193530/101). Se não tiver um motivo muito bom para esta escolha acho que foi um erro. Se tem um bom motivo deveria ser muito bem documentado, o que não achei. E [eu adoro a linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221905/101).

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Texto Em Caixa".equals("texto em caixa", ignoreCase = true));
    println("Texto Em Caixa".equals("texto em caixa", ignoreCase = false));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oSuARS). E[no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mfrgvipw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/IgnoreCase.kt).