# Organização pra futura manutenção de código quando tenho duas funções semelhantes

Tags: c#, .net, método, estilo-de-codificação

Tenho duas funções, uma retorna apenas o primeiro resultado e a outra também retorna o primeiro resultado ou retorna mais que um resultado.

Criei o parâmetro "string todos" pra definir se ira retornar um ou mais resultados na segunda função. Mas a segunda função se tornou mais complexa e eu poderia ter feito mais simples pra funcionar apenas pra retornar vários resultados

Devo continuar programando complexo igual a segunda função ou deixar-la mais simples e com um objetivo só?

Chamada pra teste:

```
    Pastas pastas1 = new Pastas(@"C:\New folder\Nova pasta\");
    Pastas.Teste1(pastas1, "3.txt");
```

Código:

```
// Mapeia todo as pastas e subpastas de um diretório
class Pastas
{ 
    public DirectoryInfo Diretorio;
    public List<Pastas> SubDiretorios = new List<Pastas>();
    public FileInfo[] Arquivos;

    public Pastas(string pasta)
    {
        Diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(pasta);

        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in Diretorio.GetDirectories())
        {
            SubDiretorios.Add(new Pastas(di.FullName));
        }

        Arquivos = Diretorio.GetFiles();
    }
// Primeira Função
// Percorre as pastas e retorna o primeiro arquivo pelo nome
    public FileInfo GetArquivo(string nome)
    {
        FileInfo arquivo = Arquivos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == nome);
        if (arquivo is null)
        {
            foreach (Pastas item in SubDiretorios)
            {
                arquivo = item.GetArquivo(nome);
                if (arquivo != null)
                    break;
            }
        }

        return arquivo;
    }
// Segunda função
    public List<FileInfo> GetArquivo(string nome, bool todos)
    {
        List<FileInfo> arquivos = new List<FileInfo>();

        if (todos)
            arquivos = Arquivos.Where(x => x.Name == nome).ToList();
        else
        {
            FileInfo arquivo = Arquivos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == nome);
            if (arquivo != null)
              arquivos.Add(arquivo);
        }

        if (todos || arquivos.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (Pastas item in SubDiretorios)
            {
                arquivos.AddRange(item.GetArquivo(nome, todos));

                bool apenasOPrimeiro = !todos;
                if (apenasOPrimeiro && arquivos.Count == 1)
                    break;
            }
        }

        return arquivos;
    }

    public static void Teste1(Pastas pastas, string nomearquivo)
    {
        FileInfo arquivo = pastas.GetArquivo(nomearquivo);
        if (arquivo != null)
            Debug.Print(arquivo.FullName);
        else
            Debug.Print("arquivo nulo");
    }

    public static void Teste2(Pastas pastas, string nomearquivo)
    {
        List<FileInfo> arquivos = pastas.GetArquivo(nomearquivo, true);
        if (arquivos.Count > 0)
            arquivos.ForEach(x => Debug.Print(x.FullName));
        else
            Debug.Print("arquivo nulo");
    }

    // GetArquivo(..., false)
    public static void Teste3(Pastas pastas, string nomearquivo)
    {
        List<FileInfo> arquivos = pastas.GetArquivo(nomearquivo, false);
        if (arquivos.Count > 0)
            arquivos.ForEach(x => Debug.Print(x.FullName));
        else
            Debug.Print("arquivo nulo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você deve fazer só você pode decidir.

Eu sempre prefiro o simples, sem ser simplório. Nem sempre é fácil dizer o que é simples. E tem que observar outras coisas, em alguns casos é melhor deixar um pouco mais complicado se tiver alguma vantagem clara em fazer isto.

Eu [odeio essa ideia de passar um booleano para dizer o que o fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227780/101) (embora há casos para uso). Fiz até uma pergunta sobre isto: [Por que não se deve usar um parâmetro booleano?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193530/101).

Neste caso não é só o booleano, mesmo usar um `enum` mais semântico não me agrada. O .NET faz isso e eu não gosto. Mas não é o fim do mundo usar. Prefiro isto que violar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), por exemplo, mas tem maneiras de ter mais de um método, um para resultado único e outro para resultado múltiplo sem violar o DRY, ainda que pode ficar um pouco mais complexo.

Este caso seu me parece que ter os dois métodos é o ideal, e o parâmetro `todos` nem deveria existir.

Note que o LINQ faz exatamente isto, tem um um método para pegar tudo ou para pegar só o primeiro e outro para pegar o *default* se nem isso conseguir.

Outra possibilidade não muito ruim é fazer um método que segue a mesma sistemática do LINQ e retornar um enumerador e aí se você quer só um ou vários pode compor uma uma *query* que faça isso de forma eficiente. Pra falar a verdade na forma criada seria o melhor a fazer. Mas eu sei que provavelmente não conseguirá fazer isto, estou colocando porque talvez seja a forma que eu eu faria.

Tem muitas soluções, mas não são perfeitas.

O código tem vários outros problemas. O uso do `.ToList()` aí parece errado. Tem certeza que precisa fazer isto? Se não sabe usar o LINQ da forma correta faça do jeito normal sem ele. Só chame o `ToList()` se quiser concretizar a lista, não parece ser o necessário nesse ponto. A solução também não é bem o que foi colocado na outra resposta, mas enfim, não vou conseguir resolver tudo aqui.

O segundo `if` parece não ser necessário, ele deveria estar dentro  do primeiro (se mantiver o `todos`). Esse `arquivos.Count == 0` parece estranho aí, principalmente porque depois tem um `arquivos.Count == 1`, mas nem posso afirmar sem entender o que precisa. Essa *flag* `apenasOPrimeiro` parece desnecessária e só existe porque o código é confuso. A questão é que esse código certamente pode ser escrito de forma mais simples.

Tenho medo desses tipos `Pastas` e `List`, isto parece algo feito errado.

Comment: Fiz uma nova resposta com um código melhor, sou novo no site, estou fazendo certo? O código esta bom?

Comment: Melhorou mas ainda não parece ideal, de qualquer forma não posso falar com propriedade porque precisaria entender todos os requisitos.

Comment: Essa é apenas uma classe pra armazenar caminhos de pastas e dados dos arquivos, pra depois eu retornar uma lista de arquivos e comparar os dados com outra lista de arquivos

Answer (score 0):

Decidi usar a dica desse link e a segunda função: [Por que não se deve usar um parâmetro booleano?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193530/por-que-n%c3%a3o-se-deve-usar-um-par%c3%a2metro-booleano)

Que seria continuar a usar o parâmetro "bool todos", mas criar funções que chamam essa função principal.

Aqui esta o código mais simples e melhorado.

```
    private List<FileInfo> GetArquivos(string nome, bool todos)
    {
        List<FileInfo> arquivos = new List<FileInfo>();

        // Forma antiga com o ToList()
        // Conceito do ToList(): é utiliado quando consolidar dados
        //arquivos = Arquivos.Where(x => x.Name == nome).ToList();

        foreach (FileInfo item in Arquivos)
        {
            if (item.Name == nome)
                arquivos.Add(item);
        }

        if (!todos && arquivos.Count > 0)
            return arquivos;

        foreach (Pastas item in SubDiretorios)
        { 
            arquivos.AddRange(item.GetArquivos(nome, todos));
        }

        return arquivos;
    }

    public List<FileInfo> GetArquivosPeloNome(string nome)
    {
        return GetArquivos(nome, true);
    }

    public FileInfo GetPrimeiroArquivoPeloNome(string nome)
    {
        return GetArquivos(nome, false).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```